# How to sort movies alphabetically in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

If you visit http://ccvideofinder.heroku.com/, it's a good example of what I'm referring to.

How can this be done in Rails? I was thinking maybe using `case`/`when` statements but after fooling around with IRB for some time I couldn't figure it out.

---

In the model:

```
class Movies < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title

  def self.find_by_first_letter(letter)
    find(:all, :conditions => ['title LIKE ?', "#{letter}%"], :order => 'title ASC')
  end

end
```

In the controller:

```
@result = Movie.find_by_first_letter(params[:letter])
```

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering

Comment: it's like he's storing movies in the letters .. a = ['ant life', 'another one'], b = ['boiler room'] - that's what confuses me.

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
# Simple Ordering    
@videos = Movie.order('title ASC')

# Implement the ordering outside of definition
@videos = Movie.find_by_first_letter('a').order('title ASC')

# Implement the order into your definition (as in example below)
@videos = Movie.find_by_first_letter('a')
```

Documentation for ActiveRecord Querying can be found:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering

---

If you wish to implement the order into your `find_by_first_letter` definition, then you can simply chain the `.order()` function as the following:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title

  def self.find_by_first_letter(letter)
    where('title LIKE ?', "#{letter}%").order('title ASC')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't understand why are you not using query chaining:

```
Movie.where('title LIKE ?', "a%").order(:title)
```

But still better, create a scope as Michael Lynch said, it will increase your code reusability.

Actually your code is giving a deprecation warning. You must check for it in your Rails server terminal window. Although it's working it's not a good idea to let that go unchecked.

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling #find(:all) is deprecated. Please call #all directly instead. You have also used finder options. These are also deprecated. Please build a scope instead of using finder options. (called from irb_binding at (irb):1)